# C++ passing by reference random output

Tags: c++

**If anyone is seeing this in the future, the answers below are great and explain in depth *why* I got this error.**

So, now I understand why I get the random output with this code. Because I did not use a return statement in the function's body.

This is my code:

```
int getNewValue(int &);

int main()
{

    int number = 5;
    cout << &number <<endl;
    cout << getNewValue(number) << endl;
    cout << number << endl;



    return 0;
}

// Function Definitions
int getNewValue(int &num)
{
    num *= 3;
}
```

**The output is:**

```
0x6dfeec
7208684
15
```

This was my original code:

```
void getNewValue(int&);

int main()
{

    int number = 5;
    cout << &number <<endl;
    cout << getNewValue(number) << endl;
    cout << number << endl;



    return 0;
}

// Function Definitions
void getNewValue(int &num)
{
    num *= 3;
}
```

But this created an error too so that is why I changed everything to return statements. The book I am following used Void function to change the variable when passing by reference. But this code above gives me an error too. How can I accomplish this with void functions?

The error I get in CodeBlocks is: error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}' and 'void')

Is this because a cout function requires a return value and a void function has no return value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this because a cout function requires a return value and a void function has no return value?

Yes. The issue is you are mixing up 2 ways of getting information from a function.

1. Passing an argument by reference:

```
void getNewValue(int &num) {
  num *= 3;
}
```

In this case the usage would be:

```
getNewValue(number);
cout <<  number << endl;
```

2. Returning a value

```
int get_num(int num) {
  return num * 3;
}
```

and the usage would be:

```
cout << getNewValue(number) << endl;
```

however this won't change the argument, so number will still be `5`. Note that *not* returning a value from a function like this is undefined behavior. Anything can happen.

If you want to both return the new value, and change the argument, to work with your use case, you can do that as well.

```
int get_num(int &num) {
  num *= 3;
  return num;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> It's the 7208684 that I don't understand. What even is that?

It is undefined behaviour.

> but why?

Because you declared that the function returns `int`, but the function doesn't return any value.

> Shouldn't the function call getNewValue(number) have 15 as the output?

You don't return 15, so why should the output be 15?

> Is there no way to call a function, which permanently changes a variable using reference

Sure there is. That's what your function does... or would do if the behaviour of the program wasn't undefined.

> and get the output in the same statement?

Simply use the return statement with the value that you want the function to return.

Example:

```
num *= 3;
return num;
```

That said, from design point of view, both modifying an argument through reference and returning a copy of the value is unnecessary and may be confusing to the user of the function.

I recommend that you follow the Single Responsibility Principle, and choose one or the other. In case of primitive objects such as integers, returning a copy instead of modifying through a reference is ideal.

---

> ```
> void getNewValue(int &num)
>
> cout << getNewValue(number) << endl;
> ```

This does not work because you declared that the function doesn't return anything, but you attempt to insert its return value into the stream. The program is ill-formed.

> How can I accomplish this with void functions?

You simply cannot accomplish this with "void functions". Their return value cannot be used because they return no value.

> Is this because a cout function requires a return value and a void function has no return value?

`cout` is not a function. `cout` is a variable. You have passed it as the left hand operand to the `<<` operator. The right hand oprand is `getNewValue(number)`. Operands of the `<<` operator must be non-void.

Comment: Yeah I changed to a return type because the book I am following uses Void functions when passing by reference just to change the variable value. I'll update my question to show my original code and error I got when using void.

Comment: Thanks for the help on this! I'm still new and a lot of books and resources are good at explaining what should happen but fall short when covering erroneous outcomes.